# Using parameter with interval in query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, intervals, psycopg2

I have this query that by default, gets all the data within the past 60 minutes (from the current time). However, the user also has the ability to select a time (thus the parameter `newTime`). I want to get all the past data within the past hour of *that selected time*.

```
@app.route('/_ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userCount():
    try:
        newTime = request.form['time']
    except:
        newTime = datetime.now()
    cur.execute("""SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) from user_table WHERE tstampz >
                   (%s::date - INTERVAL '60 mins')""", (newTime,))
    count=cur.fetchone()[0]
```

This works perfectly for the current time, yet when I change the time selection, it displays an aggregate of data from 60 minutes ago all the way back to the selected date.

**What I want:** If I select August 1st at 2 PM, I want all the data from August 1st 1 PM - 2 PM.

**What I'm getting:** All the data from August 1st at 2 PM to 60 minutes ago.

How can I make query compatible with the intervals I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have an open range

```
  WHERE tstampz > (%s::date - INTERVAL '60 mins')
```

You need close the upper limit

```
  WHERE tstampz >  (%s::date - INTERVAL '60 mins')
    AND tstampz <  %s::date
```

Be sure to validate if you need `>= <=` to include the border cases

Comment: When I try these, it gives me `IndexError: tuple out of range`. Not sure why

Comment: Im talking just about the query, you need close the range. I'm not familiar with python sintaxis, but maybe you need add two parameter at the end. something like `, (newTime, newTime)` because now you have another parameter?

Comment: other things you should try are **A)** Check what value you have in `newTime` **B)** That index error is very weird Test your query with the time hard code  `WHERE tstampz >  2017-08-01 12:00:00  AND tstampz <  2017-08-01 13:00:00`

Comment: I've been able to print out any values for `newTime`, and they are correct and in the correct format. Also, adding the second parameter as you suggested fixed my index error. However,  it's not displaying the right data and it's no longer displaying the correct data for the current time anymore

Comment: Can you test the query direct in postgresql first? Can you write what is the exact range you are looking for? For what I understand on your question the range should solve the problem. Unless you are missing the border cases.

Comment: In my example in my question I explained the range that I'm looking for (60 minutes from before the selected time to the selected time). Also could you explain what do you mean by border cases in this scenario?

Comment: border case main if you want use  `>` or `>=` to include the border of the range. But again why you say doesnt return the date you want? Did you test it using pgAdmin?

Comment: I see, I think I would want to use >=. I don't have pgAdmin, but to clarify it's returning the correct *date* but not the correct *data*. Even the data from the current time, which was working before, is wrong now

Comment: well you should have some way to query your db.  Try `SELECT * FROM ...` to check if the data returned is from that dates range.

Comment: Ok, it's hard to tell because there is so much data but it appears to show slightly off for the current time. Also, I still have the same problem where when I select a time, it is showing me all the collective data (big range)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151079/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-sarah).

Answer (score 0):

You need a closed interval and do not cast to `date`. If necessary cast to `timestamp` or `timestamptz` depending on `tstampz` data type:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) 
    from user_table 
    WHERE 
        tstampz > %s::timestamptz - INTERVAL '60 mins'
        and
        tstampz < %s::timestamptz
""", (newTime, newTime))
```